# How do I prevent the keyboard from making my recyclerview items smaller?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

So the problem is this. At first it looks good:

[image]

But when I open my keyboard the first two items in the way of the keyboard shrink a little bit

[image: recyclerview items shrink]

This is the XML code of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#EFE8E8"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Difficulty" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the XML code of my activity where the recyclerview is displayed:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".subActivities.CreateWorkoutActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.075"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:maxHeight="220dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/exerciseRecyclerView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Add"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.938"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.737" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView3"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity tag in manifest, add this line:

```
android:name=".SettingsActivity"
```

Like:

```
<activity
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  android:name=".MyActivity"/>
```

Comment: It did fix the issue with the buttons changing places when opening the keyboard, but now somehow the recyclerview gets smaller everytime I open the keyboard.

Comment: What do you expect? Keyboard takes space.

Comment: yes but I asked if there was a way to prevent that shrinking

Comment: Sorry, I didnt looked at those pictures carefully. I think there's a problem in yoir layout. Post the layout code. The answer i provided is incorrect.

Comment: You can take a look at the code now, I have made an Edit to my post